# Django Allauth Social Avatar picture

Tags: django, django-allauth, avatar

On my profile I show the usual profile picture.  The second line shows the profile picture if they have signed in using social media (Twitter in my case).  I am sure it is simple but I can't quite fathom out how to only show the relevant profile picture.  I.e. If they are signed in via social media then just the social avatar else the local avatar.  Hope this all makes sense?

```
<img src="{% avatar_url user 200 %}" width="100" height="100" alt="{{ user.get_full_name }}" />
<img src="{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}"  width="100" height="100"/><BR><BR>
```

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `{% if %}`:

```
<img src="{% if user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url %} {{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}" {% else %} {% avatar_url user 200 %}" alt="{{ user.get_full_name }}" {% endif %} width="100" height="100"/>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if